# Proving function on space has non-continuous inverse

Tags: real-analysis

Here's the question: Say $Y=([-1,1]\times \{0\})\cap \{ (x,1-x^2:x\in(-1,1) \} $ with the subspace metric of $\mathbb{R}^2$. We need to show that the function on $f:[0,2)\to Y$ given by $$ f(x) = \begin{cases} (-1+2x;1-(-1+2x)^2) ,x\in[0,1) \\ (3-2x;0)       , x\in[1,2) \end{cases} $$
is continuous and invertible, and has a non-continuous inverse.

For continuous, it it enough to show that the parts each are continuous and equal each other at x=1? For invertible, can I just show that each part is bijective - injective by showing that if f(a)=f(b) then a=b necessarily.

How do I show that it has a non-continuous inverse with what I have done?

Comment: It appears to me the domain of $f$ is $[0,1] $ and not $[0,1)$ (you have used the latter in the definition). If so, then checking bijection would be enough.

Comment: @JackLeGrüß the domain of f is [0,2). how does showing bijection show the inverse is non-continuous?

Comment: Ah, sorry! I read this as “continuous” inverse. That’s incorrect.

Comment: can anyone help?